# Django not rendering Glyphicons

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

Glyphicons are rendering as empty rectangles in my development server.

**settings**

```
from unipath import Path  

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).ancestor(2)                                   
STATICFILES_DIRS = (BASE_DIR.child("static", "static_dirs"), )        
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**template**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> 
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
```

**bootstrap.css/bootstrap.min.css**

```
src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), 
    url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), 
    url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
```

**urls**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(regex = r'^$',
        view = 'tesglyph.views.testglyph'),
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

When I add to

**base.html**

```
<head>
(...)
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css"     rel="stylesheet">(...)
</head>
```

I get the heart, but not the calendar !

How do I fix this?

Comment: did you check the generated html for accuracy? the one reason one works and the other doesnt is most likely a typo, or a conflicting class name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems excessively difficult, have you considered something like [django-bootstrap3](http://django-bootstrap3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/templatetags.html#bootstrap-icon)?

All needed would be-

```
{% load bootstrap3 %}

...

{% bootstrap_icon "heart" %}
```

Note that this solution means that you only code in the template, saving a ton of headache. Replace heart with the bootstrap icon name that you want to display. That's it.

Comment: I looked into it already, but I tend to customize bootstrap.css. Affect much ?

Comment: Not in terms of displaying icons, as long as your manual bootstrap css/js imports happens after using `{{ bootstrap_css }}` and `{{ bootstrap_js }}` so that your manual imports take precendence over the automatic imports of the load statement. View the html source of the page to see the contents of those statements and just keep in mind that last import for cad has precedence per property.

Comment: Per your 'its a local directory below' comment, you have to follow the guidelines for [static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/). You can not pull from a local directory in production, instead files in you STATICFILES_DIRS settings are searched for all used files which are then copied to you STATIC_ROOT. It's not just best practice but necessary for a functioning site to properly call static files with the proper tags. [Read up](http://blog.doismellburning.co.uk/2012/06/25/django-and-static-files/).